# How to find file and open a file if I only know part of the file name

Tags: excel, vba

I need to open file whose full name I do not know.

I know the file name is something like.

ASFC

Please help

Comment: Are you asking how to use a wildcard in a directory listing?

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54952634/edit) to let us know what you've tried so far, and how it fails to achieve the desired goal. It might also be worth your time to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to read[this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is used excel vba to open a file in "c:\rootdir\" but I don't know the file name only part of the file name as ASFC.

Comment: If you have 32 files in "c:\rootdir\" that all have "ASFC" in their names, how do you want to handle that scenario?

Answer (score 1):

It would be along the lines of

```
file1 = dir("c:\rootdir\" & "*" & "ASFC" & "*" &".xlsx")
Workbooks.Open Filename:= file1
```

But if you have more than 1 file in that directory with "ASFC" who know what it will get